# How to create numbered list inside for loop

Tags: python, list, loops

How would I go about creating a list that will store info inside the for loop. Because they keep taking in new info every loop I need a way for it to automatically create new name for the list. I hope the code clears up what I want to accomplish

```
x = 1
while x <= ItemsInList:
    str(x)+'list' = []
    x +=1
```

Is it possible to create lists like 1list = [], next loop it will be 2list = [] etc.

Comment: Briefly: you are already familiar with the `list` type. Just use a `list` to hold the others.

Comment: Oh, and names like `1list` and `2list` are not valid identifiers because they begin with numbers.

Comment: If you _need_ the names, use a `dict` to store your `list` names as keys and the lists themselves as values. If not, a list of lists as [TigerhawkT3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3) suggested will do just fine

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What do you mean under "use list to hold the others"? and would list1 and list 2 work better?

Comment: You know how you can put things into a `list`? One of the things you can put into a `list` is... another `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 alright that makses sence :D thank you!